# C# can a class be aliased (not with 'using')

Tags: c#, class, c#-4.0, types, alias

In Delphi, the following is possible:

```
class Alias = Dictionary<long, object>;
```

Alias is now a `dictionary<long, object>`.

Is this possible in C#? I've never figured out how without having to wrap the dictionary into a custom class.

The using directive won't work since it's local to the file it appears in.

Comment: It's true that a `using` alias only applies to the file (or even namespace declaration) that it is inside, but why not just repeat the same `using` alias in all relevant files? There are probably a lot of ordinary `using`s that are repeated, like `using System;` and so on, so I don't think it's a problem to have `using Alias = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<long, object>;` or similar in each file.

Comment: I am using 'using' in the way you suggested, but only in the case where the type is defined once. I don't want an alias to potentially have different meanings in different files. Just a robustness design decision I made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly.

But you can do this:

```
public class Alias : Dictionary<long, object>
{
}
```

This means you can use `Alias` everywhere an instance of a `Dictionary<long, object>` is required. But you can't use a `Dictionary<long, object>` where an `Alias` is required.

However, you could create an implicit operator to transparently convert from a `Dictionary<long, object>` to an `Alias` instance:

```
public class Alias : Dictionary<long, object>
{
    public Alias() {}
    public Alias(Dictionary<long, object> dictionary)
    {
        foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
            Add(kvp);
    }

    public static implicit operator Alias (Dictionary<long, object> dictionary)
    {
        return new Alias(dictionary);
    }
}
```

Please note that this implicit conversion operator will create a copy of the dictionary which might be unexpected or undesired.

Answer (score 4):

No this is not valid in C#.

If you want Alias to be a Dictionary you can inherit the Dictionary class like so.

```
public class Alias : Dictionary<long, object>
```